# What is the difference between NSOperationQueue and NSAutoReleasePool

Tags: iphone, nsoperationqueue, nsautoreleasepool

Can anyone give me the description of the perfect difference between `NSOperationQueue` and `NSAutoReleasePool`

Comment: They exist to solve completely different problems. What's the perfect difference between a bicycle and a television set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **NSOperationQueue** class regulates the execution of a set of NSOperation objects. After being added to a queue, an operation remains in that queue until it is explicitly canceled or finishes executing its task. Operations within the queue (but not yet executing) are themselves organized according to priority levels and inter-operation object dependencies and are executed accordingly. An application may create multiple operation queues and submit operations to any of them.

Inter-operation dependencies provide an absolute execution order for operations, even if those operations are located in different operation queues. An operation object is not considered ready to execute until all of its dependent operations have finished executing. For operations that are ready to execute, the operation queue always executes the one with the highest priority relative to the other ready operations.

**NSAutoreleasePool**
In a reference-counted environment (as opposed to one which uses garbage collection), an NSAutoreleasePool object contains objects that have received an autorelease message and when drained it sends a release message to each of those objects. Thus, sending autorelease instead of release to an object extends the lifetime of that object at least until the pool itself is drained (it may be longer if the object is subsequently retained). An object can be put into the same pool several times, in which case it receives a release message for each time it was put into the pool.

You create an NSAutoreleasePool object with the usual alloc and init messages and dispose of it with drain (or release—to understand the difference, see “[Garbage Collection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000051-SW5)”). Since you cannot retain an autorelease pool (or autorelease it—see retain and autorelease), draining a pool ultimately has the effect of deallocating it. You should always drain an autorelease pool in the same context (invocation of a method or function, or body of a loop) that it was created. See Autorelease Pools for more details.

For More Visit following guideline...

[**NSAutoreleasePool**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000051-SW5)

[**NSOperationQueue**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Hope, this will help you..

Answer (score 2):

You could have easily found this in the Apple development documentation:

[**`NSAutoreleasePool`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> The `NSAutoreleasePool` class is used to support Cocoa’s
>   reference-counted memory management system. An autorelease pool stores
>   objects that are sent a release message when the pool itself is
>   drained.

[**`NSOperationQueue`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html)

> The `NSOperationQueue` class regulates the execution of a set of
>   `NSOperation` objects. After being added to a queue, an operation
>   remains in that queue until it is explicitly canceled or finishes
>   executing its task. Operations within the queue (but not yet
>   executing) are themselves organized according to priority levels and
>   inter-operation object dependencies and are executed accordingly. An
>   application may create multiple operation queues and submit operations
>   to any of them.